# Unable to update button based on numbers of elements in a list

Tags: c#, .net, maui, maui-community-toolkit

This is a MAUI app.

I have this xaml in MainPage.xaml

```
<Button                                
  x:Name="SendPhotoBtn"
  Text="Send Photos"
  SemanticProperties.Hint="Send photos to email address"
  Command="{Binding SendPhotoCommand}"
  HorizontalOptions="Center" />
```

And i have an list of items:

```
[ObservableProperty] 
[NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(SendPhotoCommand))] 
ObservableCollection<ImageModel> _items;
```

And i want the button to be enabled/disabled based on the _items.Count.

I tried having this:

```
private bool CanSendEmail() 
{    
    return Items.Count > 0;
}
```

And this command:

```
[RelayCommand(AllowConcurrentExecutions = false, CanExecute = nameof(CanSendEmail))]
private async Task SendPhotoAsync()
{
  ...
}
```

It's getting disabled, but never enabled again.

Comment: As a test, if you remove CanExecute from attribute, does the command get executed when button pressed? To be sure everything is hooked up correctly.

Comment: Yes it does, the command works fine.

Comment: Show code that sets Items to have contents. Make sure you use Items not _items. Also, is that code called from constructor? May need to wrap in Dispatcher.Dispatch.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this method :

```
private bool CanSendEmail() 
{    
    bool checkItemsCount;

    if(Items.Count > 0)
        checkItemsCount= true;
    else
        checkItemsCount= false;

    return checkItemsCount;
}
```

And do the job for the button depending on this result.

Or :

```
private void CanSendEmail() 
{    
    if(Items.Count > 0)
        // SendPhotoBtn is enabled
    else
        // SendPhotoBtn is disabled
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I believe i shouldn't access the xaml elements from the viewmodel though. Not sure how the first method helps me?

Comment: So, on your button, do something like : ```IsEnabled="{Binding CanSendEmail}"```

Comment: @TimeShift I would also bind `IsEnabled` to the ViewModel (I am not sure that you can bind a method tho).

Comment: The problem is that you can't bind IsEnabled to a viewmodel if the button contains a Command attribute, it's not supported, it will just ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

You could put **IsEnabled** property after **Command** property then could use binding.(If you put **IsEnable** before the **Command**, then it doesn't work.) Try the following code:

```
<Button                                
    x:Name="SendPhotoBtn"
    ...

    Command="{Binding SendPhotoCommand}"
    IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}"
/>
```

Then in ViewModel, you could bind to IsEnable.

```
[ObservableProperty]
private bool isEnabled;
```

As i don't know the whole code, i just give you some suggestions here. You could use **CollectionChanged** event to detect the add or remove of an item, Each time an item is added or removed, we could update the IsEnabled property for Button.

```
    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<ImageModel>();
        Items.CollectionChanged += Items_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private void Items_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsEnabled =  Items.Count > 0;
    }
```

Hope it works for you.